The uploaded file (4.96 MB) exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini. but PHP.ini specifies Max. file size = 256 MB
I can't install a plugin on Wordpress because of the following problem:

the uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in
php.ini.

The size of the archive I'm trying to upload is 4.89 MB
The php.ini file has the following settings:

Execution time: 300 sec
Max. request size: 256 MB
Max. file size: 256 MB
Memory limit: 1024 MB

I tried the following solutions:

I wrote the line define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M'); in wp-config.php

I increased upload_max_filesize using the .htaccess file.


php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value memory_limit 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300


Increased upload_max_filesize in the function.php file.

@ini_set( 'upload_max_size', '40M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '70M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '250M');


You can not set upload_max_size and post_max_size at runtime, so attempt number 3 was pointless to begin with. Can't you just unpack the zip file locally, and then upload the plugin via FTP ...?

Have you checked the value in phpinfo()? Are you using apache? Which .htaccess file did you edit?
